# how to established a two way network link between vswitch0 and vswitch1

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi

I have a Exsi 5.1 Lab with a Freesco router which enables my private network range 192.168.1.. talk to my vm network range 192.168.0.. but not the other way around

I can ping any machine in my (vm network) 192.168.0.11 vswitch0 from private network 192.168.1.11 vswitch1 but would not work if i ping from vswitch0 192.168.0.11 to vswitch1 private network 192.168.1.11

private network (vswitch1) has no adapter assigned to it and vmnetwork (vswitch0) has vmnic0. I have tried different combination that i could think of but nothing worked

by ping i mean (access)

I need to have a access to VMS running in a private network from my (vm network) which sits on two different subnets

Can anyone please shed a light on this as i am exhausted by trying different things

Comment: In ESXi, you usually don't give IPs to vswitches; do you mean 192.168.x.11 that is connected to the vswitch? I assume that you have an ESXi host that has a single NIC physically connected to another external switch, and inside you have three VMs; two hosts, and one Freesco router, with one vNIC per host, and two vNICs for the router?  And you mentioned that both vSwitch0 and vSwitch1 have the same IP address? Can you confirm those addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there has been a IP mistype in my original post. vswitch0 and vswitch1 is of same range apart from the subnets

freesco range is 192.168.1 and it would ping and access 192.168.0 range with no issue but not the other way around

my esxi host has two nics out of which only one is in use and its connected to another external unmanaged switch

I have 9 Vms and all are in freesco router range of 192.168.1... The only reason why i need to access the 192.168.1.. from my normal 192.168.0 range is because of RDC and vcenter server which i am not been able to access from my physical machine

Each VM has one nic and just like you mentioned above, the freesco has two nics which sits both in vswitch0 (vm network 192.168.0..) & vswitch1 (private network 192.168.1..)

I hope this helps. Many Thanks